# Making Simple Post Request With Axios, React.js and Spring

Tags: reactjs, spring, rest, axios

I'm new to both React and Spring and am having trouble creating a simple JSON Post request. The post request is being logged successfully in the console but no data is being added. Here are the relevant scripts:

```
package com.sdproject.teammanager.model;

public class Team {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int seeding;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSeeding() {
        return seeding;
    }

    public void setSeeding(int seeding) {
        this.seeding = seeding;
    }

}
```

```
package com.sdproject.teammanager.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sdproject.teammanager.exception.TeamNotFoundException;
import com.sdproject.teammanager.model.Team;
@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
public class TeamController {
    private static Map<String, Team> teamRepo = new HashMap();
    static {
        Team nuig = new Team();
        nuig.setId("1");
        nuig.setName("NUIG");
        nuig.setSeeding(1);

        teamRepo.put(nuig.getId(), nuig);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/teams")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getTeam() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(teamRepo.values(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/teams", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createTeam(@RequestBody Team team) {
        teamRepo.put(team.getId(), team);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Team has been registered", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/teams/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateTeam(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody Team team) {
        if (!teamRepo.containsKey(id))
            throw new TeamNotFoundException();
        teamRepo.remove(id);
        team.setId(id);
        teamRepo.put(id, team);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Team Has Been Updated Successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/teams/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> delete(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        if (!teamRepo.containsKey(id))
            throw new TeamNotFoundException();
        teamRepo.remove(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Team Has Been Deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class TeamInput extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const Team = {
            name: this.state.name
        };

        axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/teams`, { team })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Team Name:
                        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

After hitting my button to submit a team with default parameters, I can see it being successfully submitted. But it doesn't show up in the repo or when I use postman to get the JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Java class, Team doesn't have a getter method defined. 
Either you should have used the spring annotation for getter or should have defined a getter.
This might be the root cause of your problem.
If not, could you be more clear on the issue?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my inititial question with my full Team class and full controller class. Hopefully this clarifies some things.

Comment: When i mimicked your code and tried your post request in postman to create a team.
It did reply with the added team name.
See
`[
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": "somename",
        "seeding": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "NUIG",
        "seeding": 1
    }
]`

only, issue is that the id is null.

Comment: Also,
const Team = {
            name: this.state.name
        };
 axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/teams`, { **Team** })
the object name should be same. T should be capital.

Comment: Changing from team to Team allowed me to post the request and to see the new JSON object in the repo! However I think there is an error with my event handling as the name is showing as null even though I can see the entered field being passed through in the post request.

Comment: i found your issue :)


use lowercase only for team. both in declaration of the variable team and in the axios.post request.
also, dont encapsulate team inside {}, only send the object as **team**, as given below: 

`const Team = {
            name: this.state.name
        };

axios.post(http://localhost:8080/teams, team )`

Comment: Changing the way the object was handled fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i hope it can work for you

```
async handleChange = event => {
        await this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    } 


  handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {
                name: this.state.name
          };
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: `http://localhost:8080/teams`,
          data
        })
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
               name: '',
            }); 
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
```